# redirect get request in Angular results in net::ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT 302

Tags: angular, redirect, angular-http-interceptors

I have a spring app which has a get method, which gathers some data and forms a new url, later the url is being put in the header of the response and is sent back to the caller. The problem is the Angular 11 app is not able to subscribe to the get method, as an error is thrown net::ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT 302. Opening of the get url in a new tab is not an option as the get method is protected and the angular app intercepts each request and adds the jwt token to it.

Comment: Did you check, if the returned url for redirection is valid?

Comment: yes, it is. But the issue is angular interprets 302 as error